# spark (Clean up app folders in worker nodes)

Tags: apache-spark

I need  to clean up app folder(include app downloaded jar) in spark under work folder. 
I have tried to set below configuration in spark env.But its not working.

SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true -Dspark.worker.cleanup.interval=10 -Dspark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=10"

Is there any solution to clean up the folder. 
What is the exact configuration to be given to clean the folder. 
Whether it should be give in spark.defaults.conf/spark env. 
Thanks in advance 
anitha.

Comment: Did you set it on worker nodes as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set this property also: `spark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl`

But in my case i just used custom bash script to clean work directory.